# Importing IntelliJ project to Android studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I had a project that compiled fine in Intellij 12.1.4, but I want to use android studio because of the xml editor. My problem is this, when I try to import the project into android studio 1.0 RC 4 the first error I get is:

> "You must use a newer version of the Android Gradle plugin. The minimum supported version is 0.14.0"

My original build.gradle file contains:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5+'
}
```

now simply changing it to read:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.0'
}
```

causes this error:

```
Error:(17, 0) Could not find property 'files' on  org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@2e93ad.
```

Any suggestions for what to try? My entire Build.gradle file is below

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.0'
}
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
compile files('libs/android-support-v7.jar')
//compile files('libs/GoogleAdMobAds.jar')
compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsV2')
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
compile files 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'

compile files 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
compile files('libs/amazon-ads-5.4.46.jar')

}

android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 7
    targetSdkVersion 16
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error message is because two of your dependency statements are invalid.

```
compile files 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
compile files 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
```

should be:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
```

However, I would strongly encourage you to rework your other dependencies on support And Google libraries. It's best practice to not include these as jar files but instead by accessing them via their Maven coordinates as with the appcompat and Play Services libraries. (In fact, since you've included the Play Services library as shown here, you don't also need to include its jar).

If you remove those dependency statements and go to **Project Structure > (your module) > Dependencies > + > Library dependency** it should assist you.

Additionally, using the `+` notation for the appcompat dependency should be discouraged; it can cause unexpected build breakage if the library updates underneath you. The Project Structure dialog can assist you in supplying the explicit version number of this dependency.